# Abstract database methods must return a @Dao annotated class or interface

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-room

I think this topic already existed. But, since we have a new version of room database, it will be helpful to me to understand better.
So, I am implementing a room database with the version 2.3.0 but I am getting lot of errors:

1. `Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);`
2. `Not sure how to handle insert method's return type. public abstract java.lang.Object insertStudent(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()`
3. `Abstract database methods must return a @Dao annotated class or interface. public abstract void setConnectDatabaseDao(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()`

Like said [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#kts), I added ktx extension to support suspendable meethods in Dao. But it's still giving me these errors.
Here are my code :
**app build gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    //id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
//room data base
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.4.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"


    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.0-rc01"
```

**Database**

```
@Database(entities = [Skill::class, Student::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ConnectDatabase():RoomDatabase() {

    abstract var connectDatabaseDao:ConnectDatabaseDao
    companion object{
        @Volatile
        var INSTANCE:ConnectDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context:Context): ConnectDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context,
                        ConnectDatabase::class.java,
                        "connect_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface ConnectDatabaseDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertStudent(student: Student)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertSkill (skill: Skill)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteStudent(student: Student)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteSkill(skill: Skill)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getStudent(id:Long):Student?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM skill WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getSkill(id:Long):Skill?

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student")
    fun getAllStudent():LiveData<List<Student>?>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM skill")
    fun getAllSkill():LiveData<List<Skill>?>

}
```

**Data class**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "student",
    foreignKeys = arrayOf(
        ForeignKey(entity = Skill::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("id_skill"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
            )
        )
)
data class Student (
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        val id: Long,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        val name: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name= "email")
        val email: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "id_skill")
        val idSkill: Long
        ):Parcelable
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "skill")
data class Skill (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item")
    val item:String
): Parcelable
```

Do someone knows what create the problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is as per the title so :-

```
abstract var connectDatabaseDao:ConnectDatabaseDao
```

should instead be

```
abstract fun getConnectDatabaseDao(): ConnectDatabaseDao
```

The other issues can be overcome by using SDK 30 and removing the **suspend** from `suspend fun ....` and having just `fun ....` when using 2.3.0.

e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer MikeT. So, does it means that 2.3.0 does not support suspend Dao methods ? Or there is another reason behind this

Comment: Instead of deleting suspend key word, I will use room 2.4.0-rc01 to take advantage of it.

Comment: @kamdaou that's the way to go. 2.3.0 is deprecated. Not sure what the issue is with 2.3.0 but I think it's a two way thing with either JVM or Kotlin versions as well as Room.